# How do I teleport in Zan's minimap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I can't teleport to any of my way-points. I made two and I can't teleport to any of them. I am also unable to teleport to  my latest death. I've tried this in standard single player and in a LAN world, and neither work.

Comment: Note that if you are playing in a multiplayer server, you will not ever be able to teleport between two points unless you are made some sort of administrator of the server.

Comment: i am not in a server im in single player

Comment: Have you got cheats enabled?

Comment: oh :P now i can use it :D

Comment: @shanodin I added that as an answer, but if you want to write your own saying that, I'll delete mine and upvote yours. Whatever it takes to make Community stop bumping it as "unanswered"! :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie you go ahead and keep it :) The answer is the important part :)

Answer (score 2):

The teleport feature only works if you already have permission to use the normal `/tp` command: either you have cheats enabled in singleplayer, or you're an OP in multiplayer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is go to the Gui where you add way points, select a way point, and click "Teleport To." To add a way point, hit M, Then click Waypoints.

Comment: Just clarifying this is not the GUI from the add way point hotkey, but the one through accessing the Zan's minimap menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the forge version voxel minimap wich is the same this you can press m on your keyboard,that wil bring you to minimap settings.Select the waypoint button at the bottom and that will bring you to your waypoints. Select a waypoint you want to go to and there will be a button that says teleport to and you click that, their you go you have teleported to you waypoint

Hope I answered you question correctly:)